# Suse or Debian Linux Installation on Raspberry PI 3

Tags: linux, raspberrypi, pcb-design

Is I can install Suse or Debian Linux Installation on Raspberry PI 3. I yet to try. Based on the answer I can opt for it. Because I need in particular either of this OS for my requirement in classified project. Does this PCB design supports this OS.

Any advice or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Flagged to close as entirely unrelated to Arduino.

Comment: I am newbie and I'm curious to know.

Comment: And we're Arduino users who don't know about Rasperry Pi. Maybe you should go and ask on the Raspberry Pi SE...? They may have a clue.

Comment: Is there a forum for Raspberry Pi [or] for that SE. I felt this is the one. So I asked over in here.

Comment: Yes - [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Dev - This is a serious question, Why did you think this was a forum for Raspberry Pi?  Maybe there is something that can be done to stop the confusion you had from happening again.

Comment: But its about Hardware,- the Forum. I asked phenomenal, maybe Hardware bit wired so, I think it may relevant more over here and makes sense so. It can be ridden from Hold, if you hold so. Else whatever!

Comment: what does Arduino does with ARM. What is Arduino first of all. Do I need to make this inquiry as another Question.

Comment: There are many derivatives to the Arduino Uno.  Some use different processors.  The ARM based Arduinos are one of these derivatives.  That said, the ARM based Arduinos do not run an OS.  The have a boot loader and your code is what is running.  The ARM based RaspberryPis do have an OS.  And your code is just 1 of many many programs that are run in a complex time slicing paradigm controlled by the OS.  They are completely different approaches to running your code.   So much so that questions about one really do not apply to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always best to try then post in one of the Stack Exchange groups.

This question is very general.  So the answer will also be vague as the actual porting of a Linux OS distribution to a new platform is not trivial and contains many steps.  And not all of them may have been completed to the extent to suit your needs.

Evidently you can run Debian on a Raspberry Pi.  But there are a few issues.  [Look here](https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi) and do the research to understand if these limitations will cause you to abandon this path.

As for Suse, evidently it is a "specially packaged version of SUSE".  So may not actually have all the features a normal Suse distribution has.  [Look here](https://www.suse.com/products/arm/raspberry-pi/) to decide if it will work for you.

Comment: Suse doesn't work you mean to say.

Comment: I am not find what are features might not work in Suse over what you've sighted. Sorry for Vague sense. Have you ever tried Suse anytime as a experience, in your term.

Comment: Considering the Negative Voted, but imperative post, any feature-set could be arrived. What does Suse Lags, Will I succeed atleast with X or GNOME Windowing stuff. Refer this, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099908/is-we-could-wander-on-factorial-equalities-considering-ordinals-as-discussed-in

Comment: I have not tried anything except Raspbian.    It appears to be what everyone is using.   And in the world of open source, using what everyone else has already debugged is usually the best way to go.

Comment: I am not sure why this question has not been ported to the Rraspberry Pi Stack Exchange site.

Comment: It got closed by consensus of votes before a moderator got to it, that's why. ;) Only moderators can migrate to other sites.